# How to setup User and Password for Git server

Tags: git, command-line

I have a Git server at work and i need to push my work. The server requires Username and Password as Credentials to accept pushes.
Is there any way to setup credentials?!

Comment: It sounds like you should contact your sysadmin/devops team to get push access to the repository.

Comment: The server connection is usually an SSH one, in which case your usual SSH credentials will work. And if you don't want to enter your password each time, SSH keys are the way to go.

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v`?